# Error during execution of scripts in Darwin machine

Tags: shell, awk, ksh, darwin

I'm getting the following error on a Darwin machine:

```
awk: cannot execute [Interrupted system call]
```

This is the OS version:

> Darwin ...... 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:57:01
>   PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_PPC Power Macintosh

Do you know what it might be?

Comment: What code is being run by `awk` when this error appears? Does the machine exhibit any other strangeness (memory, hard drive)?

Comment: It has a lot of jobs in cron and a lot of them give these kind of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is giving you a clue.  Somewhere a system call is being made by `awk` which is not working and the calling script is consequently being "interrupted". You'll need to narrow down the scope of the question by finding which `cron` scripts are failing with this error.  Use `grep` to look through your `cron` scripts for suspects.

From the information you've provided I'd guess that a script that uses  `awk` is making a system call (the code will be `system(some_shell_cmd)` ) to a utility that doesn't exist; is installed in an unusual location; is not on your `$PATH`; is not executable; or is itself a `perl`, `python`, or `sh` (`$SHELL`)  script for which the interpreter has either not been installed or is not functioning properly.

Comment: the weird is that we didn't change anything in the machine. Why is it doing this right now? The only problem is that we have more cpu usage than in the past, can it be related to that?

Comment: If you *really* didn't change the machine (do you have a system in place for managing configuration changes?), then the machine must have changed - possibly hardware is starting to fail or fill up (maybe `awk` is trying to create a log file and there is not enough space); or one of the jobs requires network access that is not available (i.e. a remote host is failing); or DNS has changed; or firewall; or a past configuration change was not made permanent and the machine has rebooted.  Try a "differential diagnosis" approach to narrow things down a bit.

Comment: I've changed to another machine and the problem still occurs. I know exactly which script has the error but I simply don't know what can I do to fix it. Do you know anything more?

Comment: What system call is `awk` making when this occurs?  Try running the `cron` script from the commandline with `sh -v /path/to/command` to see what might be going wrong.